# jQuery UI multiple sliders start amount the same?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I am busy with the jQuery UI sliders and now i have a problem.

I have multiple sliders and the range sliders have now the same start amount (0) as the signle sliders?

How can i fix this? I have made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ut2Uv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have the fix found myself:

```js
$(".range-slide").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".slide", $this).slider({
        values: [30, 60],
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        range: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("span.amount", $this).html("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $(".range-slide span.amount").html("" + $(".slide").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $(".slide").slider("values", 1));
});

$(".signle-slide").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".slide", $this).slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("span.amount", $this).html("" + ui.value);
        }
    });
    $(".signle-slide span.amount").html("" + $(".slide").slider("value"));
});
```